# Webscraping a login page that create with Jquery a dynamic form in submit Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, web-scraping

I have to try to webscrape this URL [Supermarket login page](https://www.carrefour.es/access?pagesitename=supermercado&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.carrefour.es%2Fsupermercado%2F%3FDPSLogout%3Dtrue&back=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.carrefour.es%2Fsupermercado%2F%3FDPSLogout%3Dtrue)

I only view with Chrome debugger when I enter my user (a valid user email) and and a password with error....

I can see this page throws a call like this:

```
Request URL: https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/accounts.login?context=R1521042408&&saveResponseID=R1521042408
Request Method: POST

loginID: [my real email for testing]
password: [any word except my real password, to get ERROR p.e. Helloooo]
sessionExpiration: -1
targetEnv: jssdk
include: profile,data,emails,subscriptions,preferences,
includeUserInfo: true
loginMode: standard
lang: es
APIKey: 3_Ns3U5-wXeiSQL-vZtu1Fd2DpWBsEdB78mYs2dn0_kyFFwwSJAZZd1EHUm9kodfND
source: showScreenSet
sdk: js_latest
authMode: cookie
pageURL: https://www.carrefour.es/access?pagesitename=supermercado&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.carrefour.es%2Fsupermercado%2F%3FDPSLogout%3Dtrue&back=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.carrefour.es%2Fsupermercado%2F%3FDPSLogout%3Dtrue
format: jsonp
callback: gigya.callback
context: R1521042408
utf8: &#x2713;
```

I tried to create a php script with cURL to invoke  this URL:
https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/accounts.login?context=something&&saveResponseID=something

and POST parameters.... but I have a problem... this page internally uses APIs to generate contexts with this result:

callback: gigya.callback
context: R1642825906

Does somebody can explain me please how this pages work, because I dont know how to regenerate this contextID  to call the login account with this URI:
https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/accounts.login?context=something&&saveResponseID=something

Please help me! I need to try to understand how this page works.
Thanks!

Ani

Comment: p.e. My testing useremail for this supermarket login page is: alamo.ani@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API key used in the login POST is hardcoded in a file `config.js`, so you can retrieve it using Regex like :

```
curl -s "https://www.carrefour.es/nlogin/resources/config.js?v=v1.0.24" | sed -rn 's/\s+val:\s+\x27(.*)\x27,.*/\1/p'
```

But it's not very nice, you would be better with an automating browser tool like [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium)

There is 2 more APIs to call for the login :

- a POST on https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/accounts.login with `saveResponseID` as query param and login, password and apiKey form-url-encoded in body
- a GET on https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/socialize.getSavedResponse with `saveResponseID` & `APIKey` as param (response in JSON format)

`saveResponseID` seems to be a sort of session id stored on server

A script using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
USERNAME="your.email@gmail.com"
PASSWORD="test"
CONTEXT=responseId

API_KEY=$(curl -s "https://www.carrefour.es/nlogin/resources/config.js?v=v1.0.24" | sed -rn 's/\s+val:\s+\x27(.*)\x27,.*/\1/p')

curl "https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/accounts.login?saveResponseID=$CONTEXT" \
     --data-urlencode "loginID=$USERNAME" \
     --data-urlencode "APIKey=$API_KEY" \
     --data-urlencode "password=$PASSWORD" \
     -c cookie.txt

curl "https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/socialize.getSavedResponse?APIKey=$API_KEY&saveResponseID=$CONTEXT" -b cookie.txt
```

Note that the last API (the one to get the response) need a cookie generated by the `/accounts.login` API

This `saveResponseID` (context) seems to have a Time To live around 2 minutes more or less. In your case if you've reused the same only in `socialize.getSavedResponse` without calling `accounts.login` before this may explain some request errors.